# Why does a "while read" loop stop when grep is run with an empty argument?

Tags: bash, shell

The following code does not work as I would expect:

(the original purpose of the script is to make a relation between items of two files where the identifiers are not sorted in the same order, but my question raises rather a curiosity about basic shell functionalities)

```
#!/bin/sh

process_line() {
    id="$1"
    entry=$(grep $id index.txt) # the "grep" line
    if [ "$entry" = "" ]; then
        echo 00000 $id
    else
        echo $entry | awk '{print $2, $1;}'
    fi
}

cat << EOF > index.txt
xyz 33333
abc 11111
def 22222
EOF

cat << EOF | while read line ; do process_line "$line"; done
abc
def

xyz
EOF
```

The output is:

```
11111 abc
22222 def
00000
```

But I would expect:

```
11111 abc
22222 def
00000
33333 xyz
```

(the last line is missing in the actual output)

My investigations show that the "grep" line is the one that leads to the early interruption of the while loop. However I cannot see the causal relationship.

Comment: `grep -e "$id" index.txt` would have avoided this outright.

Comment: BTW, I'm tempted to close this as a duplicate of one of our *many* related questions (in most of them it's ssh rather than grep eating stdin inside the loop, but I'm hard-pressed to see that making an answer non-responsive/unhelpful).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because in the third iteration with the empty line, you call process_line with an empty `id`. This leads to `grep index.txt`, i.e. no file name. This grep reads from stdin and that'll consume all your input you pipe into the `while` loop.

To see this in action, add `set -x` at the top of your script.

You can get the desired behaviour if you replace the empty id with a string guaranteed to be not found, such as

```
entry=$(grep "${id:-NoSuchString}" index.txt)
```

Comment: @Chepner I'm not sure that's really a solution. Grepping for `""` is likely to succeed for *all* lines, not just one.

Comment: @Jens It will keep the script from hanging, although the result may still not be what is intended.

Comment: @Barmar The script doesn't hang. It just feeds the stdin to the wrong process (and so terminates early).

Comment: In my context, I will not do the grep if id is empty, and I will also quote, in order to handle ids with spaces.

Comment: Or `test -n "${id}" && entry=$(grep "${id}" index.txt)`

Answer (score 1):

Changing the "process_line" function to the following might help...

```
process_line() {
        id=$1
        if [ "$id" = "" ]
        then
                echo "00000"
        else
                entry=$(grep "${id}" index.txt)
                echo "$entry" | awk '{ print $2, $1 }'
        fi
}
```

Explanation:

- if the "id" passed in is empty then just output the default
- move the grep to the else clause so it only executes when "id" has a value
- solves the problem with the missing quotes around id in the grep statement
- another thing to consider is the case where "id" is not-empty but not found in the index.txt file.  This could result in a blank output.  Adding an if statement after the grep call to handle this case may be a good idea depending on what the overall intention is.

Hope that helps

Comment: Current code tries to `echo "00000 ${id}"` when id is filled and not found. Please add quotes arond the `$id` in the grep, it could have spaces or worse.